# PHP WordPress Textarea Widget Saving Moves Text Outside of Textarea

Tags: php, html, wordpress, textarea

Alright fairly new to php so I might have some extra data attached to my code.
I have created a widget in the plugins section as advised by outside sources. I added a textarea to the widget and everything saves and updates, but the information in the text area leaves the textarea and is displayed below the textarea after saving.

as my repuation is not high enough here is a link to the image to visualize the problem [image]

Here is my code for that area.

```
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('content'); ?>">
    Text:   <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="16" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('content'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('content'); ?>"/>
    <?php echo esc_attr($content); ?>
    </textarea></label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use self close a textarea tag eg: `<textarea />`. Remove it

try

```
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('content'); ?>">
    Text:   <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="16" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('content'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('content'); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_attr($content); ?>
    </textarea></label>
</p>
```

Comment: Good Spot, Thank you that was really bugging me.